# ActiveRecord Group by 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

`Message` model

```
user_id      # owner of the message 
sender_id    # user that sent message
receiver_id  # user then recieved message 
content      # content of message
```

I have `Messages`. I would like to group them by `sender_id` and `receiver_id` as these are a "conversation thread".

When I do group I get results that look like

```
[1,3] => 5   # user 1 and 3 have 5 messages
[1,6] => 2   # user 1 and 6 have 2 messages
[3,1] => 3   # user 3 and 1 have 3 messages
```

Really [1,3] and [3,1] are part of the same 'group'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this by sorting your `sender_id` and `recipient_id` using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` (at least in Postgres and MySQL).

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93e52/5) demonstrating the SQL:

```
SELECT 
  LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id),
  GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id),
  count(*)
FROM messages
GROUP BY
  LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id),
  GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

And the `ActiveRecord` equivalent:

```
Message.group('LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)').count
```

Comment: Does not work in my current dev env. I use mysqlite for dev... haven't had need to upgrade to Postgres in dev.... maybe I should now.... but would rather not right now as I am trying to push features fast.

Comment: Any way to do this with ActiveRecord?

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is only an adapter to your DB, so you'll need to work out how SQLite would do this. Or, once you get your current result set, merge them in Ruby [like so](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/92a08).

Answer (score 2):

Using the trick provided by @Kristján, you can merge `[1,3]` and `[1,3]` in ruby instead of using SQL functions:

```
thread_messages_count = Hash.new(0)
Message.group(:sender_id, :receiver_id).count.each do |k, v|
  thread_messages_count[k.sort] += v
end
```